# importing .py file error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to import .py file and it gives the error.

```
import thinkplot
```

And the error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import thinkplot
>   ImportError: No module named thinkplotTraceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import thinkplot
>   ImportError: No module named thinkplot

But when I open `thinkplot.py` file and then writing the code `import thinkplot`, it works well. But without opening the file, it doesn't work.

There are similar questions in the forum but none of them work for me. I am new to Python. How can I fix the problem ? Also, I am using python 2.7 in a ubuntu linux. Thank you...

Comment: First try to write just `import thinkplot` (without `.py`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not write `.py`, write `import thinkplot`.
To get more information read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Sorry for that. I also tried without .py. I fixed it also above. But still gives error.

Comment: Where you file is located? In the same directory?

Comment: Thank you. They were not in the same directory. I fixed it and it works now.